# new Date() gives invalid date in App Script but works fine on console

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

`new Date("2016-01-18T15:19:00Z")` gives invalid date within App Script but it works perfectly fine on the console. How to parse this?

Comment: Does simply doing `new Date()` work? Trying to see if it is a parameter issue or an issue with the script maybe handling `Date` differently.

Comment: Wrong format, try `new Date("2016-01-18T15:19:00Z".replace(/\-/g,'/').replace('T',' ').replace('Z',''))`

Comment: You need to add the milliseconds. `2016-01-18T15:19:00.000Z`

Answer (score 1):

As SpiderPig said, the problem is that the JavaScript engine used by Apps Script  (Rhino) is too rigid in parsing datetime strings: it requires every component of `hh:mm:ss.mmm` to be present (contrary to the current ECMA standard). This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586268). Until it's fixed, use

```
new Date("2016-01-18T15:19:00.000Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slashes in date instead of dashes. Here is an example:

```
var date = new Date ('2017/12/26 9:55 am');
Logger.log(date);
```